# SPOTFIRE % of total in cross table

Tags: percentage, spotfire, subtotal

I would like to use the aggregation "% of Total" in a cross table to basically calculate the percentage of Total income per year per shop (see table below).

However, it is not calculating correctly.  It will do OVER AXIS ROWS instead of OVER YEAR:

Sum([INCOME]) THEN [Value] / Sum([Value]) OVER **(All([Axis.Rows]))**

So, i switch to the "Max" aggregation where i get the proper value. (it works also with "Min")

However, in the Sub Total per Year, it will show me the MAX value and not 100%.

Do you know how should i type my formula so when i select the aggregation "% of Total", it works correctly?

[image]